# Substituting value via shortcode

Tags: shortcode

```
function add_listing( $atts)
 { extract( shortcode_atts( array (
'sslug' => '',
'jslug' => ''
  ), $atts ) );

global $wpdb;
$qstr = '   
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts   
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)    
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = "states" 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = "publish"
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "usstates"
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "job-desc" 
AND $wpdb->terms.slug =  $sslug;   <-----
OR $wpdb->terms.slug =   $jslug;    <--------
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
';
  add_shortcode("list", "add_listing");
```

i want to subtitute the value like for example:

here's my sample shortcode

```
[list sslug="alabama" jslug="electrician"]
```

i want to subtitute the value to the arrow above

but cant get it to work :(

please help guys

Answer (score 1):

If you put variables inside a string, you have to use `"` double quotes.

So:

```
// This:
$qstr = '
SELECT *
...
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
';

// becomes...
$qstr = "
SELECT *
...
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";
```

Comment: He should be using the prepare method for those two items, but you're correct about the double quotes as well. He also has a taxonomy problem since he's got `$wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "usstates" AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "job-desc"`, which will always be false.